# Trocar icone do botão Actionbar

Tags: android

tenho este layout com este botão de coração , tem como dentro do evento de click deste botão eu trocar o icone

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tava querendo trocar o coração ai por este coração quando clicar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a resposta abaixo resolveu mais gerou um problema

Você precisa sobrescrever os métodos onCreateOptionsMenu e onOptionsItemSelected

1) Reter o MenuItem desejado:

```
private MenuItem menuCoracao;
...  
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.seu_menu, menu);
    menuCoracao = menu.findItem(R.id.id_do_seu_menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}
2) Detectar o click do menu e alterar o ícone:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.id_do_seu_menu) {
        menuCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.seu_drawable);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

eu tentei usar no onCreate assim

```
meuCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite_v);
```

deu este erro

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{praias.android.makerapp.com.praias/praias.android.makerapp.com.praias.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa sobrescrever os métodos `onCreateOptionsMenu` e `onOptionsItemSelected`

1) Reter o `MenuItem` desejado:

```
private MenuItem menuCoracao;
...  
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.seu_menu, menu);
    menuCoracao = menu.findItem(R.id.id_do_seu_menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

2) Detectar o click do menu e alterar o ícone:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.id_do_seu_menu) {
        menuCoracao.setIcon(R.drawable.seu_drawable);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: tem como eu iniciar esse meuCoração no onCreate?
tentei usar ela fora do onOptionItemSelected e não funcionou